# How to fix project template copying error?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

I am trying to create a nice project template. I have added it to Repository *(Project -> Add to Repository*). My project contains subfolders

[image]

And when I choose recently added project from File menu I get such errors
[image]

for all files in subfolders. Seems like IDE doesn't understand that it needs to create these folders for me.

How could I make IDE to understand what needs to be done?